# What are the building blocks to support a file system in an embedded system?

Tags: filesystems, device-driver

I am working on a raw/barebone embedded system, and I need to support some filesystem in it.
So I want to undestand the necessary interfaces between upper filesystem and lower block device.
Linux could be a reference, but its design is too complicated for an embedded system.

What I can think about is block_read() and block_write() interfaces which are called by filesystem to read/write data from/to block devices. Are they enough? And is there any other needed interface?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Most file systems targeted for embedded systems provide a porting interface that you need to change in-order to port the FS to your project.

The functions that you need to provide in the porting process are usually:

- read from flash
- write to flash
- erase flash
- lock flash
- unlock flash

Once the porting is done the FS should be able to create and manipulate files.

Here are some open source file systems targeted for constrained systems:

[FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html)

[SPIFFS](https://github.com/pellepl/spiffs)

[littlefs](https://github.com/littlefs-project/littlefs)